# Mathematica, nested optimization

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use the solution of Maximization, defined as a function, in another function. Here's an example:

```
f1[y_] := x /. Last[Maximize[{Sin[x y], Abs[x] <= y}, x]]  (* or any other function *)
```

This definition is fine, for example if I give `f1[4]`, I get answer `-((3 \[Pi])/8)`.

The problem is that when I want to use it in another function I get error. For example:

`FindRoot[f1[y] == Pi/4, {y, 1}]`

Gives me the following error:

> ReplaceAll::reps: {x} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>
>
> FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {-0.785398+(x/.x)} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {y} = {1.}. >>

I've been struggling with this for several days now! Any comment, idea, help, ... is deeply appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ might provide more help.

Comment: @MECU I think you mean [mathematica.se]. Most of us have migrated over there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `y` is not a number, your `Maximize` cannot be resolved, in which case the `Last` element of it is `x`, which is why you get that odd error message. You can resolve this by clearing the bad definition of `f1` and making a new one that ensures only numeric arguments are evaluated:

```
ClearAll[f1]
f1[y_?NumericQ] := x /. Last[Maximize[{Sin[x y], Abs[x] <= y}, x]]

FindRoot[f1[y] == \[Pi]/4, {y, 1}]
(* {y -> 0.785398} *)
```